# Ruby BigDecimal multiplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal, bigdecimal

I'm in trouble with Bigdecimal multiplication. I have a column:

```
t.decimal "average_price", precision: 8, scale: 2
```

My sample `average_price` looks like `"3.59280368"`. When I'm try to make some calculations with this value, I get:

```
@itam.average_price * 1000000 = 3590000
```

Why not `3592803`?

Comment: Rails? I've never used it but `scale: 2` looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes, it is Rails 4 and Ruby 2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the the [rails api documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column):

> The precision is the total number of significant digits and the scale is the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

So, in the database: `3.59280368` will be stored as `3.59`.